# Jquery ui autocomplete error not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to use the autocomplete function of jquery ui but I have a problem.

I use the external library of google:

```js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

< script type = "text/javascript"
src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" > < /script>
```

My autocomplete script

```js
$("#search").autocomplete({
  source: 'autocomplete-search.php',
});
```

I have this error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
>
> at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost/sitename/script.js:382:16)
>      at j 
>   (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:29948)
>      at k 
>   (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:30262) >undefined

Answer (score 1):

you also need to include JQuery itself into your project, before the jquery-ui include. To be able to parse this,

```
$("#search")
```

, JQuery itself is required. Try including this from google, before your other script.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, the jquery-ui.min.js file itself has JQuery in it, so the main JQuery file is necessary. JQuery-UI is just an extension. :)

Comment: That's the problem because I have already included JQuery. So I really don't know why it is not working

Comment: I was able to recreate the problem, but only when I select the ACTUAL DOM element itself and not the JQuery element. Such as document.getElementById('search').autocomplete() or $('search')[0].autocomplete() . But it seems you are selecting it the right way so I'm not sure what is happening. A couple things for you to try:  
wrap the autocomplete function in 
`$(document).ready(function(){  
});` 
or pre-select jquery element:  
var search = $('#search');  
search.autocomplete(....);

That's kinda all I can think of.

Comment: And be sure to include the actual jquery file before the jquery-ui file. The order is important

Comment: Below is my exact file working. If that doesn't work then it's something other than the code for sure. Try clearing your browser's cache for one, or using a different browser.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="search" type="text"/>
<script>
$('#search').autocomplete({
 source : 'autocomplete-search.php'
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: In my previous comments, replace the links with the full ones because they are shortened by Stack Overflow automatically it seems

Comment: Thank you. But I tried another solution than jquery ui